# Combining two columns on a id

Tags: mysql

this is my database

[database schema http://slashdir.com/php/blogg/images/bloggdb.png](http://slashdir.com/php/blogg/images/bloggdb.png)

What i want to do, is, for a given userid, show the total times he has been reported.
I have read various other questions on the matter, but I'm still stumped.

The latest query i tried was

```
select
   sum(posts.timesreported + comments.timesreported) AS total_reports
FROM 
  posts 
  INNER JOIN comments ON (posts.userid = comments.userid) 
WHERE posts.userid=5 AND comments.userid=5;
```

But this must be wrong as the number i get is much too high

Thanks!

Comment: What program did you use to print your DB schema?

Comment: This is MYSQL Workbench, very helpful for those of us that refuse to use phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE (select sum(posts.timesreported) AS total_posts_reports
            FROM  posts  INNER JOIN users ON (posts.userid = users.id) 
            WHERE posts.userid=5) 
      END 
 +
 CASE WHEN NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE (select sum(comments.timesreported) AS total_comments_reports
            FROM  comments  INNER JOIN users ON (comments.userid = users.id) 
            WHERE comments.userid=5) 
      END
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I get the exact same number with this query as the one i posted.

Comment: How is posts and users related? Is it by USERID?

Comment: Hmmm. If a user has no comments. This query will return NULL. any way around that?

Comment: If a user doesn't have comments it should still return 0+0 which is zero.

Comment: No, it returns 0 + NULL which is NULL or 2 (posts reported) + NULL (hasn't made a comment) which also is NULL apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
sum(posts.timesreported + comments.timesreported) AS total_reports
```

try

```
sum(posts.timesreported) + sum(comments.timesreported) AS total_reports
```

and I think you need to group by userId

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your collecting the sum PRIOR to singling out the user. Perhaps this is adding those column values for all users prior to the join? What happens if you SELECT *, perform your INNER JOIN where userid = 5. Save the column values as two variables and then try to add them. Do you get the same result?

This might help you error check to see if the above theory is accurate.

```
            <?php 
             // Connects to your Database 
             mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
             mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error());

             //Run Query
            $NUM1=mysql_query("SELECT Field1 FROM Table WHERE user.key=5");
            $NUM2=mysql_query("SELECT Field2 FROM Table WHERE user.key=5");

             //Print Each Result
            echo 'Num1 = '.$NUM1;
            echo 'Num2 = '.$NUM2;

             //Print Total
            $TOTAL = $NUM1 + $NUM2;
            echo 'Total = '.$TOTAL;
            ?>
```

Comment: Seems like you are on to something, because all the queries posted here up untill this point gives the exact same (wrong) number. Im not very good qith sql, can you provide a statement for this?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE posts.userid=5 AND comments.userid=5;` is unnecessary since the tables are joined.

And `sum` operator is not correct logically

Use this query

```
select
   sum(posts.timesreported) + sum(comments.timesreported) AS total_reports
FROM 
  posts 
  INNER JOIN comments ON (posts.userid = comments.userid) 
WHERE posts.userid=5
```